# Float:right property not producing desired results in CSS3

Tags: html, css, double-quotes

I have some HTML5/CSS3 code, in which I want to float the `#rightodwnblock` image right. I have added the `float: right` property to the code but for some reason the image still floats to the left. I can see nothing within the code that would cause this to happen, so I'm wondering if the issue might be server-side? It's up for testing here:

http://www.orderofthemouse.co.uk/JavascriptTesting4Client/index.html

The in-progress code is shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />
    <title>The End.</title>
    <style style="text/css">
      .marquee {
      height: 1024px;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      }
      .marquee p {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      line-height: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      font:120pt Verdana,Arial;
      /* Starting position */
      -moz-transform:translateY(100%);
      -webkit-transform:translateY(100%);
      transform:translateY(100%);
      /* Apply animation to this element */
      -moz-animation: scroll-up 20s linear infinite;
      -webkit-animation: scroll-up 20s linear infinite;
      animation: scroll-up 20s linear infinite;
      }
      /* Move it (define the animation) */
      @-moz-keyframes scroll-up {
      0%   { -moz-transform: translateY(100%); }
      100% { -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); }
      }
      @-webkit-keyframes scroll-up {
      0%   { -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); }
      100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); }
      }
      @keyframes scroll-up {
      0%   {
      -moz-transform: translateY(100%); /* Browser bug fix */
      -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); /* Browser bug fix */
      transform: translateY(100%);
      }
      100% {
      -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); /* Browser bug fix */
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); /* Browser bug fix */
      transform: translateY(-100%);
      }
      #rightodwnblock {
      top: 100px;
      float: right;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <audio autoplay>

      <source src="<!--#exec cmd="/web/stuff/bin/randfile \*.mp3 music/mp3" -->" type="audio/mpeg" autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto" />
      <source src="<!--#exec cmd="/web/stuff/bin/randfile \*.ogg music/ogg" -->" type="audio/ogg" autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto" />
          <redacted>
    </audio>
    <div class="marquee">
      <p>Blackness.</p>
      </div>
   <img id=”rightodwnblock” height=”100px” width=”100px” src="littlelogo.png" title="Do Not Click Here" alt="Do Not Click Here"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Update: I have added a float-right class to the code, so the img tag properties read as follows:

```
<img class="float-right submit-button" id="rightodwnblock" height="100px"      width="100px" src="littlelogo.png" title="Do Not Click Here" alt="Do Not     Click Here"></div>
```

This hasn't helped either. The revised code has been uploaded to the server.

Update 2: I have altered the quote tags as suggested in one of the answers below and updated the code above to reflect this change. It hasn't solved the original issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem appears to be that your text editor is not inserting quotation marks in a web-standard format.
So instead of this:

```
<img id=”rightodwnblock” ...></div>
```

Which the browser interprets as this:

```
<img id="”rightodwnblock”" ...></div>
```

When you should be using this:

```
<img id="rightodwnblock" ...></div>
```

Another problem is that you have not "ended" your css blocks; you are missing a `}` at the end right here:

```
@keyframes scroll-up {
  0%   {
    -moz-transform: translateY(100%); /* Browser bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); /* Browser bug fix */
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); /* Browser bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); /* Browser bug fix */
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }  
} /* <-- RIGHT HERE */

#rightodwnblock {
  top: 100px;
  float: right;
}
```

This caused the `#rightodwnblock` style to be ignored by the browser.

Comment: I replaced all the quotes as specificied. That seems to have solved an issue with the button being incorrectly sized, but it hasn't solved the original problem. The ```img``` still doesn't float right.

Comment: I edited my previous answer to try and solve your problem.

Comment: Ok... the client has told me he is still not seeing a ```float: right``` at that URL for some reason... He's using a Chromebook with the default OS and browser, just like me...

Comment: The only thing i can think of is trying to move the `#rightodwnblock` on the top of the list, so you make sure that there is no mismatched blocks interfering.

Comment: It appears to be working now. The client appears to have become confused by my use of an <img> tag instead of an invisible <div>, since that is what he had in mind but did not directly communicate. This caused a miscommunication which has now been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

What are you using for a text editor? It looks like your code is using 'smart quotes' in certain places, such as the ID, height, and width attributes on the img tag. The smart quotes are causing the ID attribute to be declared as id=""rightodwnblock"".

If you are using something like TextEdit to edit your code you want to ensure you have it set to edit in plain text instead of rich text, as rich text editors will sometimes replace standard quotes with smart quotes.

Comment: I am using the text editor my server rental company provide. SSH access to their server is broken, so I have no other option but to use it.

Comment: I am looking at the source-code on the server now and I see no doubled quotes on my end. Nor are there doubled quotes in the code I posted.